# Real-time reading of terminal output from server

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, subprocess

I'm trying to process images from my camera on my server and get the information after processing on my local machine in real-time. I can get necessary information as terminal outputs on my server, but I can't put this info in my python code on local machine, until my server program is running. I'm tried this code:

```
cmd="sshpass -p 'pass' ssh -Y user@ip -t 'process_image; bash -l'"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(line)
    p.stdout.close()
    p.wait()
```

But it doesn't work - it looks like this code just paused my program. I tried to write output to file and than read file from local machine, but it distorts my data. What can i do to read terminal output from server in real-time?

Comment: Try `now = p.communicate()[0].splitlines()` and then `for line in now: .....`

Comment: Or just: `for line in p.stdout: ...` which might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the output is going to be line buffered since you use `bufsize=1`, then you could just do:

```
cmd="sshpass -p 'pass' ssh -Y user@ip -t 'process_image; bash -l'"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line)
    .....
```

Of course, this assumes your command is giving you the output you expect.