# Capturing the output of a command in realtime - python

Tags: python

I see that there are several solutions for capturing a command output in realtime when invoked from python. I have a case like this.

run_command.py

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print "Count = ", i
    time.sleep(1)
```

check_run_command.py - this one tries to capture the run_command.py output in realtime.

```
import subprocess

def run_command(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd,
        shell=False,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE
    )

    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        if line == '':
            break
        print(line.strip())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_command("python run_command.py".split())

$ python check_run_command.py
(Waits 10 secs) then prints the following
Count =  0
Count =  1
....
Count =  9
```

I am not sure why I can't capture the output in realtime in this case. I tried multiple solutions in other threads for the same problem, but didn't help. Is the sleep in run_command.py has anything to do with this.

I tried running ls commands, but can't figure out if the output is printed in realtime or after the process completes, because the command itself completes quickly. Hence I added one that has sleep.

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True`? Any specific reasons? See also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908888/real-time-reading-of-terminal-output-from-server/41909186#41909186

Comment: No specific reasons. Updated the code. It still waits when I used the solution in the other page. The bufsize = 1 didn't help.